# Remote password hashing

Tags: hash

How secure would it be to have a external machine create hashes for passwords. So you would have simple webservers and one heavy machine that is being used by the webservers to create strong Bcrypt hashes. This system doesn't need to have the user's account name just the password so that would not be a security issue.

Comment: How would the passwords to be hashed arrive on that machine? Aren't you looking for an [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)?

Comment: @rene I guess it would either use a socket or a REST API. It could use HTTPS if using a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It is less secure as you have an additional machine and a communication channel to secure. You gain nothing by hashing passwords remotely.